# How can I get the "Ruled by a lord" happiness bonus modifier

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

I'm playing an AOW3 random game as High Elf.

Every time I check the happiness of an enemy I see a "Ruled by a lord" modifier which adds +100 to all of their units.

I've read in the game contents that If the leader is in the Throne City you can get a happiness upgrade, but my leader has been there for a week and nothing seems to change.

How can I get the "Ruled by a lord" happiness bonus modifier??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a human player you cannot receive this bonus.

This is a bonus that the AI gets for being Lord difficulty level. The bonus increases to +200 and +300 at King and Emperor respectively.

See [this wiki page](http://age-of-wonders-3.wikia.com/wiki/AI).

Also supported by [this steam comment thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/226840/discussions/0/613956964583321097/).

Comment: Thanks! Is that the official game wiki?

Comment: @I.G.Pascual I don't believe it is, and I don't know of an alternative, official wiki. In fact it is the only AoW3 wiki I can find, but it seems accurate.